# Repeating the same function in a query

Tags: mysql, optimization

In the below query, there are repeated calculations such as the three calls to `SUM(p.amount)`. Does MySQL re-calculate for each function call or is there some kind of memoization optimization under the hood? If not, how can this kind of query be optimized for maximum performance?

It seems like it would be faster after the first calculation to get the next one by the alias name, `total_payemnts`, but that just throws an error.

```
SELECT LEFT(c.last_name, 1) AS 'last_names',
    SUM(p.amount) AS 'total_payments', 
    COUNT(p.rental_id) AS 'num_rentals',
    SUM(p.amount) / COUNT(p.rental_id) AS 'avg_pay'
FROM customer c
JOIN payment p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY LEFT(c.last_name, 1)
ORDER BY SUM(p.amount) DESC;
```

This query runs on the [MySQL Sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) sample database.

Comment: I think the calculation is done once. You can change the order by to `ORDER BY total_payments DESC;`

Comment: And please do not use single quotes for aliases.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ just curious, why shouldnt you use single quotes for aliases?

Comment: It is a complex query; the extra `SUMs` is only a minor part of the total time consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definite answer is really difficult. However, some trials *might* give us some hints.

We start with a few data:

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(
    customer_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ;

CREATE TABLE payments
(
    rental_id integer not null,
    customer_id integer not null, --  references customer(customer_id),
    amount numeric(10,2) not null
) ;

INSERT INTO customers 
VALUES 
  (1, 'A - Customer 1'),
  (2, 'B - Customer 2'),
  (3, 'C - Customer 3'),
  (4, 'D - Customer 4') ;

INSERT INTO payments
VALUES
  (1, 1, 900.0),
  (2, 1, 800.0),
  (3, 1, 500.0),
  (4, 1, 900.0),
  (5, 2, 500.0),
  (6, 2, 500.0) ;
```

We first define a `DETERMINISTIC` (although it *has* side effects) function to *log* calls:

```
CREATE FUNCTION log_numeric(_n numeric(10,2), _counter character(2))
    RETURNS numeric(10,2)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
      UPDATE log SET n = n + 1 WHERE counter = _counter ;
      RETURN _n ;
    END ;
```

We have previously defined a `log` table, to just store counts:

```
CREATE TABLE log
(
    counter character(2) primary key,
    n integer default 0
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO log 
VALUES
    ('x', 0),
    ('L', 0),
    ('T', 0),
    ('N', 0),
    ('L2', 0),
    ('T2', 0),
    ('N2', 0) ;
```

At this point, if MySQL were able to just perform the [common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) optimization (common for compilers), it would just make ONE call when we issue:

```
SELECT
    log_numeric(30, 'x') AS c1,
    log_numeric(30, 'x') AS c2 ;
```

Because `log_numeric(30, 'x')` would return the *same* value in both cases (because the function is deterministic).

In fact, it makes two calls to this function, as proven by watching counter 'x';

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    log
WHERE
    counter = 'x' ;
```

[NOTE: Tested with MySQL 5.7.12]

It **might** be the case that MySQL has decided that the `log_numeric` function has some side effects, or that User Defined Functions *do not work* the same way as *built-in* functions. Built-in functions could be optimized, whereas UDF would not. In any case, if MySQL would have optimized the two expressions with just one call, it would be clear that this optimization is standard. As it did not, we can make an **educated guess** (**which is not the same as a proof**) and assume that the functions are called as many times as they're present.

The same can be done with the case posted:

```
SELECT 
    log_char(LEFT(c.last_name, 1), 'L') AS last_names,
    log_numeric(SUM(p.amount), 'T') AS total_payments, 
    log_numeric(COUNT(p.rental_id), 'N') AS num_rentals,
    log_numeric(SUM(p.amount), 'T') / log_numeric(COUNT(p.rental_id), 'N') AS avg_pay
FROM 
    customers c
    JOIN payments p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY 
    log_char(LEFT(c.last_name, 1), 'L')
ORDER BY 
    log_numeric(SUM(p.amount), 'T') DESC;
```

And the results point to all calls being evaluated as many times as they appear.

You can check all theses tests at http://rextester.com/ZKS91815.

---

NOTE: For curiosity, postgreSQL (9.6.1) does a little better: it recognizes the ORDER BY and GROUP BY as "already computed" on the `SELECT`, but it doesn't optimize either for Common subexpression elimination. Room for improvement.

### Alternative query avoiding repeating functions

If you're worried things are computed more than necessary, use:

```
SELECT
    last_names, total_payments, num_rentals,
    total_payments / num_rentals AS avg_pay
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        log_char(LEFT(c.last_name, 1), 'L') AS last_names,
        log_numeric(SUM(p.amount), 'T') AS total_payments, 
        log_numeric(COUNT(p.rental_id), 'N') AS num_rentals
    FROM 
        customers c
        JOIN payments p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
    GROUP BY 
        log_char(LEFT(c.last_name, 1), 'L')    
) AS q0
ORDER BY
    total_payments DESC ;
```

I honestly don't think the difference will be much. The weight of the functions in the time spent for the whole query is probably (ver) small. It might be signficant if the functions were complex. Depending on how MySQL deals with Subqueries (that might be temporary tables), this could actually be worse.

Comment: I think this is about as good an answer as I'm going to get. I guess the only thing left to do is verify in the source code of community edition what is actually going on under the hood. However, I'm not well enough versed with the code base or the language to do so.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** yes, there is sort of a memorization.

Anything I could test suggested that your `SUM()` function is NOT calculated twice, so your original query was already optimal.  That said, this is deep internal behaviour, so not something you'd likely find in the MySQL docs.  The the way to know for sure is to actually look under the hood in the source code for MySQL to see how it actually works.  Fortunately the code is pretty well commented, so you don't need to be fluent in C.

In source code file `sql/item_sum.cc`, there's a comment that says this:

```
Don't do anything if
1) this is an unresolved item (This may happen if an
   expression occurs twice in the same query. In that case, the
   whole item tree for the second occurence is replaced by the
   item tree for the first occurence, without calling fix_fields()
   on the second tree. Therefore there's nothing to clean up.)
```

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/sql/item_sum.cc

My reading of this is that among the many things that gets done when you write a query, the parser has to break apart your statement.  We're looking only at the `SELECT` part of the query, though there's just as complex stuff that happens to break down any `JOIN`s, `GROUP`s, `ORDER`s.  One of the thing that is done to the `SELECT` fields is that the expressions that make them up are loaded into into an "Item tree", which is a memory structure.  The server then has to "resolve" those items, which includes things like checking whether the object exists and whether you have privileges to access it.  If the same expression is seen twice, per the code comment, the "whole item tree for the second occurrence is replaced by the item tree for the first occurrence".

I don't claim to be a MySQL internals expert, so I could be wrong on this, but seeing this code comment was enough to convince me that the design isn't naive: MySQL doesn't simply read your query from left to right and execute everything it encounters.

Side note, to optimizing the performance of this query, don't look to the `SUM()`, like @Rick said, you won't find the slowness there.  Look instead to potential indexes.

Comment: Good insights and good link. Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:  If there is any performance difference, it is minor.

Long Anser:

The main cost in any query is accessing the rows and their columns.

Since the `ORDER BY` list is different than the `GROUP BY` list, there is necessarily a sort.  This is very likely to be an in-memory sort.

Working backward...  The `GROUP BY` will probably also require a sort.  Run `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to see the details.  It may, however, do the `GROUP BY` in a hash in memory, there not needing a sort.

In your particular query, I would do `GROUP BY 1` -- it's a bit cryptic, but it makes it clear that I am grouping by the #1 item in the `SELECT` list, not some slight variation on it.

Back to the original question.  Without looking into the code it is impossible(?) to tell whether the Optimizer creates "common subexpressions".  Or, in my case whether it actually recomputes the `LEFT...` when I say `GROUP BY 1`.  Either is feasible.

Writing a subquery and/or using a temp table is certainly slower.  I said that fetching rows/columns is more costly than expressions -- well, subqueries and temp tables means even more rows/columns to be fetched *and* written.  Ditto for Stored Functions and Prodecures, but for other reasons.

There *are* cases where a subquery can speed things up. but your example is not one of them.  With the important columns split across two tables, you are stuck with `JOIN` *first*, then `GROUP` and `ORDER`.

Answer (score -2):

This not happen like this. Query runs for a single row at one time and for functions like count,sum,group by and order by it create a temporary table

If there are repeated calculations then the in payment table contains multiple entries of customer table due to which this is happening.

you can write Sub Query for this:-

```
SELECT LEFT(c.last_name, 1) AS 'last_names',
    SUM(t.amount) AS 'total_payments', 
    COUNT(t.rental_id) AS 'num_rentals',
    SUM(t.amount) / COUNT(t.rental_id) AS 'avg_pay'
FROM customer c
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT p.customer_id as customer_id,
              p.amount as amount,
              p.rental_id as rental_id
              FROM payments ) as t ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY LEFT(c.last_name, 1)
ORDER BY total_payments DESC;
```